# Thinning contour lines in a binary image

Tags: python, image-processing, binary

I have a binary image with contour lines and need to purify each contour line of all unnecessary pixels, leaving behind a minimally connected line.

Can somebody give me a source, code example or further information for this kind of problem and where to search for help, please?

Comment: I did a Google search for "graphics algorithm thinning lines" and got quite a few hits.  Did you try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for python implementations, have a look at [scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/).

[One of their examples](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_medial_transform.html) is essentially your use case.

Alternately, if you wanted to stick to "straight" scipy, you can do this by using successive [erosions and dilations using `scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#module-scipy.ndimage.morphology). (As @AxezDNyde mentions.)

**Edit:** Links fixed.

Answer (score 4):

There is a actually an algorithm for that called Zhang-Suen thinning algorithm. You can find its code here: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Zhang-Suen_thinning_algorithm

Also I wrote a vectorized version of that in Python which is around 10 times faster than that code. Here is the code:

```
def neighbours_vec(image):
    return image[2:,1:-1], image[2:,2:], image[1:-1,2:], image[:-2,2:], image[:-2,1:-1],     image[:-2,:-2], image[1:-1,:-2], image[2:,:-2]

def transitions_vec(P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9):
    return ((P3-P2) > 0).astype(int) + ((P4-P3) > 0).astype(int) + \
    ((P5-P4) > 0).astype(int) + ((P6-P5) > 0).astype(int) + \
    ((P7-P6) > 0).astype(int) + ((P8-P7) > 0).astype(int) + \
    ((P9-P8) > 0).astype(int) + ((P2-P9) > 0).astype(int)

def zhangSuen_vec(image, iterations):
    for iter in range (1, iterations):
        print iter
        # step 1    
        P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9 = neighbours_vec(image)
        condition0 = image[1:-1,1:-1]
        condition4 = P4*P6*P8
        condition3 = P2*P4*P6
        condition2 = transitions_vec(P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9) == 1
        condition1 = (2 <= P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+P7+P8+P9) * (P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+P7+P8+P9 <= 6)
        cond = (condition0 == 1) * (condition4 == 0) * (condition3 == 0) * (condition2 == 1) * (condition1 == 1)
        changing1 = numpy.where(cond == 1)
        image[changing1[0]+1,changing1[1]+1] = 0
        # step 2
        P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9 = neighbours_vec(image)
        condition0 = image[1:-1,1:-1]
        condition4 = P2*P6*P8
        condition3 = P2*P4*P8
        condition2 = transitions_vec(P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9) == 1
        condition1 = (2 <= P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+P7+P8+P9) * (P2+P3+P4+P5+P6+P7+P8+P9 <= 6)
        cond = (condition0 == 1) * (condition4 == 0) * (condition3 == 0) * (condition2 == 1) * (condition1 == 1)
        changing2 = numpy.where(cond == 1)
        image[changing2[0]+1,changing2[1]+1] = 0
    return image
```

Comment: What kind of image does it need to work on ? I am neither a computer wiz or an signal/image processing wiz, what type is image in zhangSuen_vec(image, iterations ? Guess iteration is just an int ?

Answer (score 1):

A combination of erosion and dilation (and vice versa) on a binary image can help to get rid of salt n pepper like noise leaving small lines intact. Keywords are 'rank order filters' and 'morphological filters'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package available on PyPi called [thinning](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/thinning/) that you can just pip install. It implements the thinning algorithm by Guo and Hall for bumpy arrays / opencv grayscale images.